# Apache Mod_Rewrite specific URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm just trying to make one specific redirect. After some googling, I try this:

```
RewriteRule http://domain.com/Quest/ http://domain.com/blank-parent-page/quest/ [R]
```

and it does't work. Just want to re-write that one URL. I can successfully do it for ALL urls with `blank-parent-page` in front of them, I just can't get specifics to work. I just want the page from `http://domain.com/blank-parent-page/quest/` to show when someone goes to the URL `http://domain.com/Quest/` I'm very new to this. I'm sorry for stupid question.

Also, by rewriting this way, will it still work if someone were to use `www.` before the domain or if there was something like `http://domain.com/Quest/?final=stuff`

Thanks for taking the tome to read this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want the `http://domain.com/` as part of your regex pattern of a rewrite rule, that'll never be part of the URI.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Quest/?$ http://domain.com/blank-parent-page/quest/ [R,L]
```

That rule needs to be in the htaccess file in your document root.

> Also, by rewriting this way, will it still work if someone were to use www. before the domain

yes, it will still work as long as both are pointing to the same document root.

Answer (score 0):

That rule should be rewritten as:

```
RewriteRule ^Quest/ /blank-parent-page/quest/ [R,L,NC]
```

Since `RewriteRule` only matches REQUEST_URI not the full URL with http and domain name.